# Configure custom AdBlock Plus filter lists subscriptions

Tags: adblock-plus

Using a desktop PC version of AdBlock, I can subscribe to any combination of filter lists, and so I do subscribing to *EasyList + Czech*, *Russian* and *German* lists (I am a polyglot user using many languages actively) as well as *EasyPrivacy*, *Fanboy's Annoyances* lists, etc.

But in the mobile AdBlock Plus, I could only find a set of exclusive (choose-one) *EasyList + a national list couples*, not even featuring a Czech list at all.

Needless to say, I could neither find a way to set up custom filters of my own.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With the Android version you can't have custom filters or subscriptions, you can only use what comes with the app.

Comment: Also, having a special filter set just for facebook would be awesome, where we can block out certain columns as well as have the ability to pick and choose what "we thought you might like this" areas of the page.

Comment: You might want to read about the site a little -- [see here](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour).  We're different from a forum in that we *don't* want people to chime in if they agree or disagree, that's what voting is for.  Q&A, not discussion or polls.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature request to [Add custom filter (subscription) support (ticket #257)](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/257), but it's not yet implemented at the moment.

---

That said, **if your device is rooted**, you can manually *customize the **filter*** (not the subscription list, but the filter itself). However, by doing this, *you'll lose the automatic filter update*.

The interesting file is located on `/data/data/org.adblockplus.android/files/patterns.ini`. Take note that it's quite a big text file, and I personally recommend to edit it on a computer. The file has some sections defined by square brackets (`[...]`), and the filter starts after `[Subscription filters]`.

For the starter, you can mix'n'match the filters from [main subscription list](https://hg.adblockplus.org/adblockpluscore/file/tip/chrome/content/ui/subscriptions.xml) (look for `url` inside `<subscription>` for the filters). If you're an advanced user, or feeling experimental enough, take a look at [Writing Adblock Plus filters](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

After you're done with the customized filters file, I recommend to backup it somewhere safe (you certainly don't want to lose your hard work). Before overwriting `patterns.ini`, open Adblock Plus app and go to **Advanced Settings**, then set the **Subscription refresh** to **Manually**. Otherwise, the app will overwrite your filters.

Now, the AdBlock Plus should be using your customized filter!